# Modify global environment when rendering RMarkdown document

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

Consider this minimal RMarkdown example, saved in the file `test.rmd`:

````
```{r}
foo <- "bar"
```
````

If you render this file with `rmarkdown::render("test.rmd")`, the object `foo` will be found in your global environment:

```
> foo
Error: object 'foo' not found
> rmarkdown::render("test.rmd")
[...]
Output created: test.html
> foo
[1] "bar"
>
```

Likewise, if `foo` have been defined in the global environment, it will be modified:

```
> foo <- "baz"
> rmarkdown::render("test.rmd")
[...]
Output created: test.html
> foo
[1] "bar"
```

So far, so good.

However, for reasons of my own I want to wrap another function around `render()`, e.g.

```
myrender <- function(f) render(f, output_format="html_document")
```

Now, when I call `myrender("test.rmd")`, the `foo` variable is exported to the parent environment, in this case, to the environment within `myrender`, and I can no longer access it from the global environment:

```
> myrender("test.rmd")
[...]
Output created: test.html
> foo
Error: object 'foo' not found
```

While this is the expected behavior, I would still wish the `render` to modify the *global* environment. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me prefix this by saying that I believe this is a very bad idea. Rendering should happen in its own scope, and ideally its own R process, precisely to avoid interference (I’d even go further: the fact that this works by default is a correctness flaw in the API).

But you can pass an evaluating environment to `rmarkdown::render`:

```
myrender <- function(f) render(f, output_format = "html_document", envir = globalenv())
```

Comment: OK, so here is the rationale: when I use the cache mechanism, switching between document_outputs resets the cache. If rendering takes a couple of hours, as it does for some of my projects, this is extremely annoying. The function I am using makes a copy of the rmd with a different name (like *_html.rmd) and renders the copy. That way, I have two caches, one for each document output type, and do not have to render the slow parts again, whether I am creating PDF or HTML.

Comment: @January Fair enough. It’s still a dirty hack but I can’t come up with a better solution now.

Comment: Frankly, I don't understand why the cache needs to be reset, I think generating the markdown is a separate step from converting it to the output document. Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: @January You could ask a separate question regarding the caching issue. I guess I know the answer, but I cannot be sure without seeing a reproducible example. Thanks!